# Where to include truststore files in project

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to learn about SSL and have successfully made a client/server program that communicates over an SSL connection. I have generated my own truststore and keystore files that I would like my client and server programs to use. So far I am able to run both programs with through the command line using the following commands:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 ServerMain.java
```

and

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456 Client.java
```

However, I would like to know if there is a possible way to implement the files into my project somehow so that in the future when I build it into a .jar file, I can bundle the files with it. Previously, I had done something similar with images by storing them in a res folder which is in my project folder and used "/res/image.jpg" as a path and it worked fine. I have tried the same method by using the `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/res/mySrvkeystore.jks")` but it keeps returning file not found. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Include the keystore in your JAR file as a resource, as you did for your images.
2. Access it via `getResourceAsStream().`
3. Use that `InputStream` to load a `KeyStore.`
4. Use the `KeyStore` to initialize a `TrustManager.`
5. Use the `TrustManager` to initialize an `SSLContext.`
6. Use the `SSLContext` to create your `SSLSocketFactory.`
7. Use the `SSLSocketFactory` to create your `SSLSocket.`

Comment: Hmm I have never seen this stuff before. Could you perhaps show me some example code or point me to where I might be able to find something that can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I managed to set up the InputStream and use it to initialize a KeyStore. However, I am now lost as to how to use the KeyStore to initialize a TrustManager. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.