# Is there anyway to specific truststore in runtime (java solution)?

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc

I want to call jdbc connection in SSL mode. But current solutions are all related to set truststore into system properties, such as

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore_name 
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

Or

```
Properties systemProps = System.getProperties(); 
systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/yourTruststore.jks");  
systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustStorePassword");  
System.setProperties(systemProps);
```

However, this method would be very danger while other application also uses/changes this system variable.

So, is there any way could inject truststore in runtime but not impact on system level configuration?

Thanks

Comment: You need to read the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

Comment: You have to create your own SSLSocketFactory, and from that you can inject your own TrustManager, and that gets to decide which certificates to trust.

Comment: Well that's all back to front actually @Thilo. You have to create (1) a `TrustManager`, (2) an `SSLContext,` and then (3) an `SSLSocketFactory.`

Comment: Here's a step-by-step (and there are a few...) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21177453/14955